# Is Big Ben visible from the British museum?

Tags: uk, london, sightseeing

First time in the UK for business. I have a small free window in the morning, which - as a Greek - of course would like to spend on the British museum.

Is Big Ben visible from there? I will go tomorrow morning, clear sky. I am only interested in taking a picture with Big Ben and me..

I mean it's not named Colossal Ben, so I am wondering..

Comment: Perhaps from its roof... but not from street level.

Comment: Is the roof of the museum publicly accessible? That explains why it's not called Colossal Ben 

Comment: Why would you go to _British Museum_ if you're only interested in Big Ben? Why not go _there_ instead?

Comment: Also bear in mind that it's currently covered in scaffolding.

Comment: Big Ben that is (or technically it's Elizabeth Tower that is covered in scaffolding).

Comment: I am interested in the museum, as mentioned in my question. However, if I could get Big Ben also from there, that would be nice. Oh MJ, thanks for the warning!

Comment: I doubt that the museum roof has public access. It does not seem so from the model on Google Earth, or any info on the BM website.

Comment: I think Weather Vane, that we have an answer in a comment then!

Comment: Judging from Google Maps 3D view it looks like you can indeed spot the scaffold-clad Elizabeth Tower from the roof dome of the British Museum -- but only due to a convenient gap between the taller buildings on Oxford Street. It's more than 2 km away, though, so binoculars would be recommended. And there's no particular sign that the dome is accessible to visitors at all.

Comment: If you can make it to the Shard Tower (I got in for £25) you'll get a view of everything.

Comment: The Shard is half again as far from the British Museum as the Palace of Westminster itself is, though.

Comment: As mentioned the (former) Clock Tower is called Elizabeth Tower. [Big Ben](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben) is the name of the largest **bell** that strikes. Note you can see the present state of the scaffolding on a webcam [here](https://www.visitlondon.com/things-to-do/sightseeing/london-attraction/webcams-of-london).

Comment: @WeatherVane It's only been called the "Elizabeth Tower" since 2012. Big Ben is a perfectly valid and much older name for it (since the tower itself was nameless).

Comment: @MJeffryes - it wasn’t nameless. Prior to being renamed Elizabeth Tower, it was called St. Stephen’s Tower.

Comment: @ChrisMelville no it wasn't: https://www.parliament.uk/about/living-heritage/building/palace/big-ben/enquiries/ (spoiler: it was called the clock tower - victorian journalists called it st Stephen's tower)

Comment: @MD-Tech Well that’s told me! ;) But still, it was *called* St. Stephen’s Tower, even if not officially named. Loving the pedantry.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it's technically named. It matters *what people call it*. That's how language works. For almost all purposes, the whole structure is Big Ben. Because that's what everyone calls it. It's fine. Everybody chill.

Comment: Wow! All because I posted a piece of trivia, about the bell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The British Museum is located a short-ish (20-30 minutes) walk from Big Ben, so the distance isn't a problem in seeing it. But the British Museum is surrounded relatively closely in that direction by streets with buildings of 4-5 floors, which block the view.

I can't entirely rule out that there may be *some* spots in the grounds from which you can just about see the top of Big Ben poking above the other buildings, but you certainly won't get a good view of it. (Arguably, you can't get a good view of it from *anywhere* right now, as pointed out in the comments it's currently covered in scaffolding due to renovations)

Some comments on the question suggested it may be visible from the roof of the British Museum. That seems likely, based on google maps 3d view, but I see nothing on the British Museum's [website](https://www.britishmuseum.org/visiting.aspx) to suggest roof access is possible - and even if it were, the distance is such that I expect it would be difficult to get a good picture of you with the tower anyway.

Comment: As of January 2019, the last time I was there, there was no rooftop access at the British Museum.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to somehow scale and stand on the southeast corner of the roof of the British Museum, then the scaffolding presently enveloping the Elizabeth Tower (popularly known as Big Ben, after a bell that resides within it) would just be visible. See https://www.google.com/maps/place/London/@51.5208233,-0.1268642,46a,35y,174.37h,79.23t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!8m2!3d51.5073509!4d-0.1277583 . Big Ben is the dark brownish grey blob apparently next to (although really a long way from) the bright orange facade of Renzo Piano's Google London HQ. You would certainly be arrested in this endeavour, so it's not to be encouraged.

Comment: Yeah better not go to jail 

Comment: @gsamaras it is a good way to extend your stay in London and you could see inside some more historical buildings... well police stations... *I'm not recommending this!*

Comment: Wormwood Scrubs, Pentonville,.. Southwark Magistrates Court